# How to check why a process stopped?

Tags: process, log

How can I check why a process was stopped / killed in Ubuntu?

I know using dmesg I can check if a process is killed by OS.

But can some one let me know if the process is killed by a user, how can I know which user killed the process?

Comment: Aside from OOM errors, there's no reason why any process being killed by the OS would logged, unless the process itself does logging.

Comment: Is there any tool I can use that will monitor a process and let me know when it was killed, how & by whom?

Comment: You could catch the usual signals and handle them different within the process. E.g. writing your own `isKilled` function where you can log what exactly was the signal and where it came from..

Comment: I am not the author of the program. I am looking for some monitoring tool.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find out why process was killed on server](https://askubuntu.com/questions/709336/how-to-find-out-why-process-was-killed-on-server)

Comment: @Elder Geek - saw that. I am looking for some way to monitor a process and know why a process stopped. The question you shared talks about if only OS stopped the process. I want to know also if some other user stopped the process.

Comment: @tuk I guess I'm not the only one not entirely clear what you are asking for. Let's try this. why what process was stopped? Stopped by another user  how? Without access to the server, really?

Comment: @ElderGeek - Updated the question.

Comment: There's no general answer to this question since the kernel doesn't record why or even by whom a process was terminated. If it's a child process of the current process, you can at least find out whether the child was terminated by a signal and, if so, by what signal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only solution to your question that I can think of (assuming that you know the details of the process) would be to parse the history file of those users that would have the permissions necessary to terminate the process in question for a command that would terminate it.

This would of course require that you have permission to access the users in question .bash_history file. And would also require that the user in question was oblivious as to how to or didn't bother to turn off their own history.

I consider the odds of both of these conditions being met highly unlikely, so perhaps [this comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/969000/how-to-check-why-a-process-stopped?noredirect=1#comment1555475_969000) is more accurate in the real world.

However, regardless of the likelihood of both these conditions being met, it is possible.